# Shutdown log Linux UserName

Tags: shutdown

Can I know who issued the `shutdown` command on any *nix system in a multi-user system. ? I want to know the name of the user who issued the particular command. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Typically a normal user only has access to the shutdown command via `sudo` and `sudo` commands are (typically) logged under `/var/log/`.  The line may look like:

```
Dec  7 19:58:08 SomeHost sudo:      jimbob : TTY=tty1 ; PWD=/home/jimbob ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/shutdown -h -t 5 now
```

This example shows that the shutdown on Dec 7 was caused by user jimbob.

Since the syslog priority defaults to "notice" (a fairly low priority) for *successful* commands, you won't see these entries unless you have a log file set up to save such messages when sent from facility "authpriv".

Everything about `sudo` and `syslog` is configurable.  So, you may have to hunt around on your system and/or adjust things to find these messages.